# Why specified content is not printed in log using batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I have to print the following content like:

`Filesnames are collecting by this user abcdef in ghijkl on Date: 15-10-2015 Time: 12:39:13 from the Source Folder:` (**Content missed here**)

Should be printed in the LOG file:

Filesnames are collecting by this user **abcdef** in **ghijkl** on Date: 15-10-2015 Time: 12:39:13 from the Source Folder: **d:\destination\folder\**

And copied file names are also missing.

This is the source:

```
@echo off
Title Filenames Collector
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  set HR=%time:~0,2%
    set HR=%Hr: =0% 
    set HR=%HR: =%
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do     rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)
Echo. 
set /p UserInputPath=Enter Your Path:
cd %UserInputPath%
dir /b > C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Filenames.txt
start C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Filenames.txt
exit
:colorEcho
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1i
Echo. 
ECHO Files names are collecting by this user %USERNAME% in %ComputerName% @ %USERDOMAIN% on Date: %date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4% Time: %HR%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2% from the Source Folder: %UserInputPath% >>\\..\Filenames_by-%USERNAME%-%ComputerName%_%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%_%HR%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.log
```

Really appreciate, if someone solve this issue.

Comment: have u tried echo %UserInputPath% >> Test.txt   (for testing purpose)
just before the line .. Filesnames are collecting by this user .....

Comment: There's a typo in the `del` command line at the end: `del "%~2" > nul 2>&1i` -- remove the trailing `i`...

Comment: You should check the log entry and look if it's composed/expanded correctly by removing the redirection `>` temporarily...

Comment: Thanks @aschipfl and @amit dayama. Now it works good after relocate the line `ECHO Files names are collecting by this user %USERNAME% in %ComputerName% @ %USERDOMAIN% on Date: %date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4% Time: %HR%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2% from the Source Folder: %UserInputPath% >>\\..\Filenames_by-%USERNAME%-%ComputerName%_%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%_%HR%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.log` before the command `exit`.